# How to bring back merge commits after an interactive rebase

Tags: git, rebase

The repo was interactive rebased and it basically rewinded everything into a single linear branch and got rid of merge commits and branches.

Is there a way to bring back merge commits after flattening the history with interactive rebase like this?

The changes are force-pushed already.

I imagine something with branch filtering should do the trick, but can't quite figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, "undo" what has been done:

`git reflog` will provide a list of historical HEADS (a.k.a what 'the current SHA' has been). Every single individual SHA involved in the rebase, including the one right before any rebasing happened, should still be in that history somewhere (assuming they haven't expired).

Find that "before any rebasing happened" SHA and name it (git GUI viewers like `gitk`, or GitKraken may help):

```
git branch before-rebase-flattening <SHA>
```

Now, redo your rebase, but with `--preserve-merges`. Use a fresh branch in order not to mess with your "backup" `before-rebase-flattening` branch:

```
git checkout before-rebase-flattening
git checkout -b rebase-attempt
git rebase -ip <whatever you did before>
```

If at any point, you mess up and want to retry the rebase:

```
git rebase --abort
```

If your rebase succeeds and `rebase-attempt` is how you like it, then take your original branch, move it to `rebase-attempt`'s SHA, and cleanup the rebase branches:

```
git checkout <your original branch>
git reset --hard rebase-attempt
git branch -D rebase-attempt
git branch -D before-rebase-flattening
```